# Capybara selenium chrome get cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, capybara

We use `:cookie_store` for our Rails sessions (Rails 5.1.3), see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Session/CookieStore.html

Using `Capybara::RackTest::Driver` in a test, I can get the current session and cookies using

```
page.driver.request.session
page.driver.request.cookies
```

But when I use `Capybara::Selenium::Driver` I only have access to the cookies, not the session, e.g.

```
page.driver.browser.manage.all_cookies
```

Is there a way to access the session of the browser using Selenium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the apps session by installing rack middleware in the test environment. One gem that provides this feature is [rack_session_access](https://rubygems.org/gems/rack_session_access), however you should really ask yourself why you want to access the session in the first place.  Feature/System tests (where Capybara is used) are intended to test the app end-to-end and accessing the session directly is usually a bad smell in those types of tests.

Comment: thanks for your answer! I need access to the session to provide a convenient way to check if a user is logged in, that will be used in multiple tests. Of course I could check some interface hints if a user is logged in, but they are not always there, and the only reliable way would be to visit the users profile.